# Python, pandas. Куда копать?

Tags: python, дата, pandas

Совсем недавно стал изучать Python и сейчас ломаю голову над одной задачей:
Есть два dataframe:

```
user    date/time
a   01.02.2018 
a   01.03.2018 
a   15.03.2018 
b   01.02.2018   
b   02.02.2018
```

и вторая таблица

```
user    date/time
a   01.01.2018 
a   02.01.2018
a   02.02.2018 
a   01.03.2018 
a   14.03.2018  
b   01.01.2018
```

Можно ли без использования циклов подсчитать, сколько строк во второй таблице лежат во временном диапазоне для каждого пользователя из первой таблицы? Т.е. например для user "a" подсчитать:

1. Сколько строк во второй таблице, которые раньше `01.02.2018`,
2. которые лежат между `01.02.2018` и `01.03.2018`,
3. лежат между `01.03.2018` и `15.03.2018`
4. позже `15.03.2018`.

В итоге хочу получить примерно следующее:

```
user    date/time      count_in_table2
a   before 01.02.2018  2
a   01.02.2018         1
a   01.03.2018         2
a   after 15.03.2018   0
b   before 01.02.2018  1
b   01.02.2018         0
b   after 02.02.2018   0
```

Единственное, что я придумал, это использование циклов с кучей ветвлений и условий, но я пониаю, что это не решение. Хочется научиться использовать магию pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def my_cut(data, dates, **kwargs):
    assert isinstance(data, pd.Series)
    assert isinstance(dates, pd.Series)
    dates = dates.sort_values()
    bins = pd.to_datetime([pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')] + dates.tolist()  + [pd.to_datetime('2200-01-01')])
    dts = dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').values
    labels = ('<= ' + dts).tolist() + ['after ' + dts[0]]
    return pd.cut(data, bins=bins, labels=labels, duplicates='drop',  **kwargs)

(d2.groupby(['user',
             d2.groupby('user')['date/time']
               .apply(lambda g: my_cut(g, dates=d1.loc[d1.user==g.name, 'date/time']))
            ], as_index=False)
   .size()
   .reset_index(name='count_in_table2'))
```

результат:

```
  user      date/time  count_in_table2
0    a  <= 2018-02-01                2
1    a  <= 2018-03-01                2
2    a  <= 2018-03-15                1
3    b  <= 2018-02-01                1
```